# AJAX request returning 'object object'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying and looking for the solution to this, I have the following script but unfortunately, it returns `object object` in return

```
var states = (function () {
  var states = null;            
  $.ajax({                
    type: 'POST',
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "../home/GetAllTags",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {                    
      states = data;
    }
  });
  return states;
})();
```

I know I can do a loop to add it to a string but I require Json, not string. Also, I am clearly defining that the output is json `'dataType': "json",` still I am not sure why I am getting `object object`.

Any idea?

Cheers

**EDIT**: Controller which returns json

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllTags()
{
    List<Models.Tags.MTag> Tag_List = new List<Models.Tags.MTag>();
    Tag_List = GenerateList.Tags();
    var TAGS = Tag_List;
    return Json(TAGS.Select(t => new { id = t.Tag_id, val = t.Tag_name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

EDIT 2 - Full script

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
            return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex; 
                matches = [];
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
                $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {

                        matches.push({ value: str });
                    }
                });
                cb(matches);
            };
        };

        var states = (function () {
            var states = null;            
            $.ajax({                
                type: 'POST',
                //'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': "../my/GetAllTags",
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {                    
                    states = data;
                }
            });
            return states;
        })();               

        alert(states);

        var tags = $('input.stateinput');
        tags.tagsinput();

        $(tags).each(function (i, o) {
            var taginput = $(o).tagsinput('input');
            taginput.typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
                autoselect: true
            }, {
                    name: 'states',
                    displayKey: 'value',
                    source: substringMatcher(states)
                }).bind('typeahead:selected', $.proxy(function (obj, datum) {                   
                    $(o).tagsinput('add', datum.value);
                    taginput.typeahead('val', '');
                }));
            $(taginput).blur(function () {
                taginput.typeahead('val', '');
            });
        });

    });



</script>
```

**Results** :

[image]

Comment: when you declare `dataType:'json'` then you expect either array or object just as you are getting. JSON is the string data format sent from server

Comment: Also **never ever use** `async:false` . It is a terrible practice and is deprecated. Look at the warnings in your browser console

Comment: `still I am not sure why I am getting object object` is that what the server responds with? is var states === `"[object Object]"` - there's no indication in your code snippet as to why you think states is that "value" - i.e. how are you **using** states?

Comment: I have a controller which sends back a JSON Results (i updated the main post)

Comment: @charlietfl I am returning json results from my controller

Comment: Your update adds very little to your question. @JaromandaX's question *"how are you **using** states?*" is really the only thing that needs clarification

Comment: `but I require Json, not string` - JSON **is** a string

Comment: @Phil i added a full script -  I am using it for typeahead and tagsinput

Comment: `alert(states);` will alert `states.toString()` ... as `states` is an object, {}.toString === [object Object]

Comment: ... and there's your answer. Use `console.log` for debugging, not `alert`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Related: [javascript alert function won't show objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27385181/218196)

Comment: @Phil no, Its not an Alert issue, Look at this, this is what i get in my results- https://imgur.com/a/Oqo5R

Comment: @aliusman whatever it is, it comes down to you attempting to use an object in a string context. I suggest adding some breakpoints in your code and using the debugger to step through it line by line

Comment: @Phil thanks for the feedback, although I am unsure how to use Object as a string in this context as there are multiple objects coming out of my controller

Comment: `alert(states)` will not print the result of `../my/GetAllTags` directly. Remember: Asynchronous results.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez i removed the `alert(states)` i am using it as typeahead - see here please https://imgur.com/a/Oqo5R

Comment: At a guess, `str` in your `$.each` loop is **not** a string but is itself, an object

Comment: @Phil if i pass this as states `var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];` It works perfectly, i am trying to figure out how to convert `states` objects to strings so i can pass it to my `substringMatcher` so it can work the way it works when i pass the raw data

Comment: ::: *i am trying to figure out how to convert states objects to strings*: `JSON.stringify(states);`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thank you so much for this, i am very new javascripts, ok now I get the values as the following `[{"val":"tag1"},{"val":"tag2"},{"val":"testing"},{"val":"test2"}]` what i need is only the val' - like i want to have it in this format `['tag2','testing'];` and so on

Comment: Something like this:

`var data = [{"val": "tag1"}, {"val": "tag2"}, {"val": "testing"}, {"val": test2"}];
var result = data.map(function(x) { return x.val;});`

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thank you so much but i get the error `states.map is not a function`

Comment: Ok got it, thanks for help , i had to `PARSE` it and then `MAP` it - @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez can yu please answer the question and i will mark it as answered. `var newstates = $.parseJSON(states);
        var newstates3 = newstates.map(function (x) { return x.val; });`

Comment: @aliusman You can see my answer. I've added details with some examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157531/discussion-between-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez-and-aliusman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i suggested in the comments, to convert:

```
[{"val":"tag1"},{"val":"tag2"},{"val":"testing"},{"val":"tes‌​t2"}]
```

to:

```
["tag1", "tag2","testing", "test2"]
```

You can use [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var states = [{
  "val": "tag1"
}, {
  "val": "tag2"
}, {
  "val": "testing"
}, {
  "val": "test2 "
}];
var result = states.map(function(x) {
  return x.val;
});
console.log(result);
```

**Parsing JSON String to Object:**

You could use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

> **JSON.parse()**
>
> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string,
>   constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.
>   An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a
>   transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

```js
var states = [{
  val: "tag1"
}, {
  val: "tag2"
}, {
  val: "testing"
}, {
  val: "test2"
}];
console.log(typeof states); // => object
states = JSON.stringify(states);
console.log(typeof states); // => string
states = JSON.parse(states);
console.log(typeof states); // => object
```

> **jQuery.parseJSON()**
>
> Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript
>   value.

```js
var states = [{
  val: "tag1"
}, {
  val: "tag2"
}, {
  val: "testing"
}, {
  val: "test2"
}];
console.log(typeof states); // => object
states = JSON.stringify(states);
console.log(typeof states); // => string
states = $.parseJSON(states);
console.log(typeof states); // => object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So finally:

```js
var states = [{
  val: "tag1"
}, {
  val: "tag2"
}, {
  val: "testing"
}, {
  val: "test2"
}];
states = JSON.stringify(states);
var newstates = $.parseJSON(states);
var newstates3 = newstates.map(function(x) {
  return x.val;
});
console.log(newstates3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: JavaScript Array]